# Issue with css precedence and Bootstrap, background colors

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Visually this project is just a pyramid of Bootstrap columns. But due to the nature of how bootstrap classes are named, some colors are overriding others. The order should be green->blue->purple. But right now it is green->purple->green. The innermost column controls the color of the column, when I really want the outermost column to control the color.

I looked up how to change class names in Bootstrap, but it seems difficult and definitely outside of the scope of what they want us to do with the project.

I've been at this for awhile and don't see an easy workaround.

HTML:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-4 text-center">
    fourth layer
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class= "row">
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
      fith layer
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-center">
      fifth layer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

 <div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class= "row">
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      sixth layer
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      sixth layer
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
      sixth layer
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    color:white;
}

.col-4{
    background-color: green;
}

.col-5{
    background-color: blue;
}

.col-6{
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Comment: euh, you know that you can add your own class, right ? so my complicating your life ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would be one way to produce the desired effect.

A rule like `.col-5 .col-6` means:

If there's an element with the class `.col-5` that contains somewhere inside of it (no matter how deeply nested) an element with the class `.col-6`, then apply the corresponding rules to it.

Here's the snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<style>    
    .col-4{
        background-color: green;
    }

    .col-5 .col-6{
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .col-6 .col-4{
        background-color: purple;
    }
</style>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4 text-center">
        fourth layer
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-5">
        <div class= "row">
            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                fith layer
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-center">
                fifth layer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class= "row">
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                sixth layer
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                sixth layer
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 text-center">
                sixth layer
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I mean, it's not clear why you don't just use `id`s or custom classes for that.

Comment: Thanks, hardly ever code in html so didn't know about that nested functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background for every child based on the parent's class, like this:

```css
body {
  color: white;
}

.col-4 {
  background-color: green;
}

.col-5 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.col-6 {
  background-color: purple;
}


.col-4 div {
  background-color: green !important;
}

.col-5 div {
  background-color: blue !important;
}

.col-6 div {
  background-color: purple !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-4 text-center">
    fourth layer
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 text-center">
        fith layer
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 text-center">
        fifth layer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        sixth layer
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        sixth layer
      </div>
      <div class="col-4 text-center">
        sixth layer
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```